# Yellowbrick prediction error graph edit lables and legends

Tags: python, machine-learning, visualization, yellowbrick

I want to plot prediction-error using Yellowbrick visualizer but i am not getting the desired results. The plot is similar to the pp plot or a qq plot which is not correct. Also i am not able to change the labels of the axes and add title nor am i getting any by default labels and legend. 
can anyone please tell me what should i do.
here's the code for visualizer:

```
def predict_error(model):
    visualizer = PredictionError(model)
    visualizer.fit(X_train, Y_train)  # Fit the training data to the visualizer
    visualizer.score(X_test, Y_test)  # Evaluate the model on the test data
    visualizer.show()
```

This is the output i am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We recently had a contributor add a QQ plot feature to our `ResidualsPlot`, and while that commit is not deployed *quite* yet, until then, you can fork and clone Yellowbrick using [these instructions](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/develop/contributing/getting_started.html#forking-the-repository), and then create QQ plots as follows:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts

from yellowbrick.datasets import load_concrete
from yellowbrick.regressor import ResidualsPlot

# Load a regression dataset
X, y = load_concrete()

# Create the train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=37
)

# Instantiate the visualizer,
# setting the `hist` param to False and the `qqplot` parameter to True
visualizer = ResidualsPlot(
    Ridge(), 
    hist=False, 
    qqplot=True,
    train_color="gold",
    test_color="maroon"
)
visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train)
visualizer.score(X_test, y_test)
visualizer.show()
```

Here's the result:
[image: Example of QQ-plot with Yellowbrick]